Using community edition (Alexandra) with intraweb. I get message: [dcc32 Fatal Error] Firstwebserverapp.dpr(11): F2613 Unit 'FastMM4' not found
Having selected file>new>other>intraweb>application wizard I get these messages: [dcc32 Fatal Error] Firstwebserverapp.dpr(11): F2613 Unit 'FastMM4' not found. What to do?
I tried to run the intraweb word wizard having just installed it.
